# Global Blog Post and Duplicate Content Penalties When Using hreflang For Language and Regional URLs

Tags: seo, google-search, duplicate-content, hreflang, localization

I am setting up a European regional website (translated). We will be using hreflang For Language and Regional URLs. If we post a global product update blog post, i.e. is relevant to all markets, would the following cause Google duplicate content penalties? This is the same post, only translated when presented in a different language. For example; 'en' will be the exact same content, 'fr' exact same but in French, 'de' exact same but in German.

```
example.com/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ (en-gb)
example.com/en/fr/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ (fr-gb)
example.com/en/de/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ (de-gb)
example.com/fr/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ (fr-fr)
example.com/fr/en/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ (en-fr)
example.com/fr/de/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ (de-fr)
example.com/de/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ (de-de)
example.com/de/en/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ (en-de)
example.com/de/fr/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ (fr-de)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
example.com/fr/en/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/ 
example.com/de/en/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/
```

must be marked as canonical to

```
example.com/blog/2017/01/global-app-update-new-feature/
```

and the same way for French and German translated pages.